# Need help Converting to Prolog rule

Tags: prolog

Everybody likes a job if it's fun and it pays

`we=>likes(X, Job):-fun(Job), pay_well(Job)`.

Not sure if it's correct and if it matters that I put Job as a variable?

Comment: You can have `Job` as a variable, sure, as long as you want it to be one (*i.e.*, your rule pertains to any job, not one particular job). `likes` isn't a very good name, though. Likes what? You should call it something more meaningful, perhaps: `likes_job`. Also, what about `X`? What is `X`? Is there a constraint on `X`? What if a job is fun and pay swell. Then this would be true: `likes_job(elephant, Job)`. I suppose that's Ok if an elephant can have a job. Alternatively, you can restrict `X` to be a person: `likes_job(X, Job) :- person(X), fun(Job), pay_well(Job).`.

Comment: @lurker oh now I get it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just provide definitions for the other two predicates and you have a working program. Something along these lines:

```
likes_job(_Person, Job) :-
    is_fun(Job),
    pays_well(Job).

is_fun('scuba diving instructor').
is_fun('tour guide').

pays_well('software developer').
pays_well('scuba diving instructor').
```

A couple of examples:

```
?- likes_job('Peter', Job).
Job = 'scuba diving instructor' ;
false.

?- likes_job('Peter', 'software developer').
false.

?- likes_job('Peter', 'tour guide').
false.

?- likes_job('John', 'scuba diving instructor').
true.

?- likes_job(X, 'scuba diving instructor').
true.
```

Instead of defining the two predicates, you can just declare them as "dynamic" and they are now *empty* (instead of absent):

```
likes_job(_Person, Job) :-
    is_fun(Job),
    pays_well(Job).

:- dynamic is_fun/1.
:- dynamic pays_well/1.

$ swipl -q
?- [likesjob].
true.

?- likes_job(A, B).
false.

?- assertz(is_fun(x)).
true.

?- assertz(pays_well(x)).
true.

?- likes_job(A, B).
B = x.
```